# Unsupported Operand Type(s) ; Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a counter that saves the amount of key-presses to a text file.

This is the code atm.

```
import keyboard

count = open("count.txt", "w+")
amount = count 


while True:  
   if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):  # if key 'q' is pressed
       print("This idiot has pressed the spacebar " +
                         str(amount) + " times!")
       amount = amount + 1
       count.write(amount)
```

Which returns this error;

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: '_io.TextIOWrapper' and 'int'
```

I think I understand why I'm getting this error, but I want a second opinion.

What I think is happening, is that the .txt isn't using the right encoding; e.g UTF-8.

Comment: `amount` is an `TextIOWrapper` object. What do you mean by `amount = amount + 1`?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting `amount = count` to do, and why?

Answer (score 2):

`count` is a TextIOWrapper object, if you want to read the contents, you should `read()` the file.

```
import keyboard

count = open("count.txt", "w+")
amount = count.read() 


while True:  
   if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):  # if key 'q' is pressed
       print("This idiot has pressed the spacebar " +
                         str(amount) + " times!")
       amount = int(amount) + 1
       count.write(amount)
```

Comment: It's throwing this at me: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: File "count.py", line 17, in <module>
    amount = int(count.read())

Comment: How about changing the code to the edited one? I am reading in str and changing to int in the if block.

Comment: File "count.py", line 24, in <module>
    amount = int(amount) + 1
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: I'm guessing the error is arising for empty spaces, Can you print the value of amount and confirm the same. Add ```print(amount)``` right before line 24 in your code.